# django-rest-framework how to resolve a URI reference to object

Tags: django-rest-framework

How does one, using the django-rest-framework, resolve a URL parameter (to a View function, say) to the referenced model object (or queryset)? I understand how to have a ModelViewSet/Serializer pair to allow CRUD operations on a particular model object, but for some other View function that takes, for example, two model object URLs as parameters, how that View function can turn these URLs into the corresponding querysets?  Clearly, one could parse the URLs manually, extract the "model" and "id" portions of the URL and retrieve the corresponding queryset.  But this seems a fundamental operation in django-rest-framework and is performed automatically when you have ModelViewSets with HyperlinkedModelSerializers and foreign key fields in those models. I need to do this in an arbitrary environment, not tied to a model and foreign keys. I simply want to resolve the URLs to querysets.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link: [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/)

Basically you should be able to get what you want by

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

view = resolve(url).view_name
```

And from here you can get either a .model or .queryset from the view.

Comment: Please be more explicit on "And from here you can get either a .model or .queryset from the view".